# Adaptive Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg method constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

in text book

Runge - Kutta - Fehlberg method

$ \tilde{w}_{i+1} = w_i + \frac{16}{135}k_1 + \frac{6656}{12825}k_3 + \frac{28561}{56430}k_4 - \frac{9}{50}k_5 + \frac{2}{55}k_6\tag1$

is 6order Runge-Kutta method and

$ w_{i+1} = w_i + \frac{25}{216}k_1 + \frac{1408}{2565}k_3 + \frac{2197}{4104}k_4 - \frac{1}{5}k_5 \tag2$   Runge-Kutta 5 order

then why coefficient is below?

$ k_1 = hf(t_i,w_i)$

$ k_2 = hf(t_i+\frac{h}{4},w_i+\frac{1}{4}k_1)$

$ k_3 = hf(t_i+\frac{3}{8}h,w_i+\frac{3}{32}k_1+\frac{9}{32}k_2)$

and $ k_4,k_5,k_6$ and so on.

and why (1) formula has $w_i$ instead of $ \tilde{w}_i$

and I don't know why this method don't use Runge - Kutta method order4 and 5 or  4 and 6 instead of order 5 and 6

Comment: and i don't know why the constant is same of two different order method

Comment: I studied  this book chapter . but i do not understand this part. so i asked

Comment: this book do not explain my question.

Comment: How sure are you about your order assignments? 6 stage Runge-Kutta methods have maximally order 5, there is no 5-stage order 5 method, so the method in (2) has order 4 which makes this the 4(5) embedded RKF method.

Comment: my mistake  not order but step

Comment: I want to know why constant is that and why the same constant of two diiferent step is

Comment: Why what? The coefficients in the Butcher tableau follow from some selections in the time steps of the stages and an algebraic system of order conditions. Wilhelm Kutta in 1901 found that this is a very compact and economic form for an ODE integration method. Did you understand the order 2 and 3 methods (of Heun or the RK1234 family)?

Answer (score 1):

Steps you should follow:

- Understand and implement some low-order RK methods (or copy the code) and run some example ODE.
- Understand the idea of variable step size and that control of the step size tries to obtain a mostly uniform error density, each time step contributes a part to the global error that is proportional to the time step.
- Step doubling and Richardson extrapolation allow to estimate the local error and determine an optimal step size. Find out that this requires a very high effort.
- Embedded methods re-use the same right-hand-side evaluations for two methods of different orders. These are highly tuned methods with nearly no visible, intuitive structure in the coefficients.

---

As for the cited embedded system, order 4 with an embedded order 5 step for the error estimator:
From the construction of the method you get that $w_{i+1}=\tilde w_{i+1}+Ch^5+O(h^6)$ and the local error of $\tilde w_{i+1}$ is $O(h^6)$, so that $$w_{i+1}-\tilde w_{i+1}=Ch^5+O(h^6)$$ is a valid estimate of the dominant term $Ch^5$ of the step error of the 4th order method and can be used to adapt the step size to the desired global error level.