# Runge Kutta Fehlberg method (RK45) for coupled ODEs

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

As a little summer project I have tried to make a ballistic calculator for when I play football, (following an example from a book), just to learn some numerical methods while doing so. My problem is that I cant seem to find much on the Runge-Kutta 45 method (method recommended) for systems of differential equations.

My equations (simplified a bit) is

$ \cfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = K_x(y) \cdot \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2} \cdot \dot{x} + C_x(y) $

$ \cfrac{d^2y}{dt^2} = K_y(y) \cdot \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2} \cdot \dot{y} + C_y(y) $

$ \cfrac{d^2z}{dt^2} = K_z(y) \cdot \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2} \cdot \dot{z} + C_z(y) $

With the initial conditions being

$\dot{x}(0)=v_{x0}$,
$\dot{y}(0)=v_{y0}$,
$\dot{z}(0)=v_{z0}$.

$x(0)=x_0$,
$y(0)=y_0$,
$z(0)=z_0$.

I have rewritten the problem to

$ \cfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = f(t, x, y, z, \dot{x}, \dot{y}, \dot{z}) $,

$ \cfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = f(t, x, y, z, \dot{x}, \dot{y}, \dot{z}) $,

$ \cfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = f(t, x, y, z, \dot{x}, \dot{y}, \dot{z}) $,

And from there changed the second orders to first orders by

$ \dot{x} = \xi $,
$ \dot{y} = \zeta $,
$ \dot{z} = \phi $,
$ \dot{\xi} = f1(t, x, y, z, \dot{\xi}, \dot{\zeta}, \dot{\phi}) $,
$ \dot{\zeta} = f2(t, x, y, z, \dot{\xi}, \dot{\zeta}, \dot{\phi}) $,
$ \dot{\phi} = f3(t, x, y, z, \dot{\xi}, \dot{\zeta}, \dot{\phi}) $

Which gives me the system

$\cfrac{d}{dt}[x, y, z, \xi, \zeta, \phi]^T = [\xi, \zeta, \phi, f1(t...), f2(t....), f3(t....)]^T $

I think my next step is to calculate the 6 rk45 K values for each of the 6 equations?, but im a bit lost in the whole method at this point, and literature is a bit vague on this topic (at least for what i have found so far)

Comment: How much do you know about the RKF method? Have you implemented it for the scalar case to your satisfaction? What programming environment do you use, do you have a vector object type? What step size controller do you use? Do you follow the intended 4th order method or do you use the extrapolation idea using the 5th order step? Note that the DoPri methods are more optimized for extrapolation.

Comment: I have no experience with the Runge-KIutta method, kinda just jumped into it since it was the recommended method in a book called "Military ballistics - a basic manual" but the book just explains the physics, so it might be overkill for this kind of IVP(and to complicated for a noob). I'm coding in python.

Comment: Then I'd recommend to use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`, the default method is DoPri45. In the documentation you can also find examples for coupled systems, as vectors are used `numpy` arrays. // If you want to go more in the details of the methods, you could follow the steps in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3303869

Comment: I'm trying to learn the RK45 method because I have a course where we use matlab's ode45, but i don't like using commands i don't understand, therefore I would calculate the first 1 or 2 time steps by hand to fully understand it, and thereafter make a python solver, tho the scipy sounds like a good way to check any results so thank you! and ill definitely read those steps from the link

Comment: Note that ode45 uses one of the variants of the Dormand-Prince coefficients, not the Fehlberg coefficients. An almost complete implementation of RKF to experiment with can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978904/understanding-the-local-truncation-error-of-an-adaptive-runge-kutta-integrator. The only thing to change for a system is to use norms instead of the absolute value in the error estimate. For simple methods with more visible errors see the idea in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63001637/3088138 to use the linked 3rd order methods as embedded 2-3 methods.

Comment: I thought the book "Numerical Analysis" by J. Douglas Faires and Richard L. Burden did a decent job describing the Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg Method.

Comment: To start with, a similar problem with fixed-step RK4 as method was discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61337796